# java program cannot create file folder in the system.why?

Tags: java

I am working on project and in which I make a program to create a file folder in system. When i run my program it shows:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:File 'E:\Program
>   Files\IBM\SDP\Profin\EmailAttachment\30189\31609\T0000021811.pdf' does
>   not exist

My code is:

```
    public EmailQueueAttachment[] get(Long emailQueueId)throws InvalidDAOArgumentException {
    if (emailQueueId == null) {
        throw new InvalidDAOArgumentException("Email Queue Id  can not be null.");
    }
    EmailQueueAttachmentListHelper criteria = new EmailQueueAttachmentListHelper();
    criteria.setEmailQueueId(emailQueueId);
    List<Model> emailQueueAttachmentList = getList(criteria, -1, -1).getCurrentPageData();
    if (emailQueueAttachmentList != null) {
        EmailQueueAttachment[] attachments = (EmailQueueAttachment[]) emailQueueAttachmentList.toArray(new EmailQueueAttachment[emailQueueAttachmentList.size()]);
        for(int i=0; i<attachments.length; i++){
            try {
                attachments[i].setAttachmentContent(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(SystemUtil.getEmailAttachmentFolderName() +  File.separator + emailQueueId + File.separator + attachments[i].getRecNo() + File.separator + attachments[i].getAttachmentName())));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new DAOException(e);
            }
        }
        return attachments;
    }
    return null;        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the parent folder exists where you want to create the file

You can use `File(parent).mkdirs()` before trying to write your file

Comment: Well... First I wanted to upvote... but then I read the code and found a `readFileToByteArray()` - no help in creating parent directories here...

Answer (score 0):

The code you have performs a

```
FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(somePath);
```

Obviously, that File is just not there. So most likely the process that was required to *write* that file to that location did not work.

**You** have to decide what to do in these cases. Currently you *fail* the whole attachment-generation stuff. Maybe you'd be better of adding a default attachment in this case with some text "Attachment data not found in storage" or something.

Comment: well then - can you share how you solved it and upvote/accept answers accordingly?

Comment: mr. jan my read file and write file memory area were not same